# Make a navbar stick to top of page

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I don't know javascript, and I think that i am going to need it here. Can someone pls help me with making the navbar visible on the top off the page as you scroll down the page?

```css
.nav{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin-top: px;
}

.nav > li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.nav >li >a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav >li > a:hover{
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
      </ul>
      
hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>
```

Comment: _I don't know javascript_ Good because you don't need it for this! Look into the CSS property called [`position`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp), the value you'll want is `fixed`

Comment: You can refer to this tutorial ; 

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `position: fixed` and give some `padding-top` as same as the `height` of the `nav` to the body:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 75px;
}

.nav {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
}

.nav>li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.nav>li>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav>li>a:hover {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
</ul>

hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to set a `position: fixed` for your navbar

```css
.nav{
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  margin-top: px;
  position: fixed;
}

.nav > li{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 50px 0 50px;
}

.nav >li >a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.nav >li > a:hover{
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hey</a></li>
      </ul>
      
hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>hey<br>
<br>
```